Possibility of rolling of a sphere up a very rough incline
Is it possible that a ball  kept on a rough inclined plane rolls purely without slipping (immediately or after some time) ,when it is struck in a manner that it acquires only linear velocity along the incline and no angular velocity.Also, what will be the direction of friction while moving up the incline?
My thoughts on it:
The friction in this case must act down the incline, to oppose the relative moton.
Since the friction and a component of gravity acts down the incline, the velocity of the body decreases while it's angular velocity increases. Soon the condition,
Linear velocity= Radius × Angular velocity
Is satisfied and the body's lowest point is no longer slipping on the incline. Since the relative motion is now stopped, is it necessary that the friction still acts down the incline? At this instant the situation has become the same as a ball  having both linear and angular velocities, on a very rough incline.The ball is not slipping and the friction should act up the incline to maintain this no slipping condition.  If the friction keeps acting down the incline, then the condition:
Linear acceleration= Radius × Angular acceleration
Will never be satisfied and the body will never roll.If however, it starts acting up the incline it can make the body roll without slipping.
I am fully aware that rolling will occur after the ball stops and moves down the incline. My only concern is the moving up part.

Do you mean "struck" or "stuck"

Striking the ball at the center allows no torque and so it will get only linear velocity.
